# New applications are opening at different window locations

Tags: unity, 11.10, window

I am facing this issue on a new version of Ubuntu 11.10. When I open applications they are opening at different screen locations like right top, right bottom, left bottom.

I want applications to open at the center of the screen.

Please suggest a solution to resolve this issue.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First, install [compizconfig-settings-manager](http://packages.ubuntu.com/compizconfig-settings-manager) [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager] <-- by clicking here or running

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Then open it and search for something like **Put Windows** or **Place Windows**. In it change the option from **smart placement** to **center**.

Comment: Thanks a lot satuon. It resolved the issue. Why ubuntu fail to configure such little important configurations :(.. it is definitely not good for new comers.