# Force Unity to open new window on the screen where the cursor is?

Tags: 12.04, unity, multiple-monitors

I have 2 screens and I set it as expanded desktop so that there is like one desktop expanding to another screen.

Anyway, when I open any app from Dash they automatically position themselves on Screen 1, top left corner. Regardless of the fact that the cursor is on the right screen.

How can I set windows opening on the screen where the cursor is?

Comment: This article helped me

http://askubuntu.com/questions/66648/new-applications-are-opening-at-different-window-locations

Answer (score 6):

Install compizconfig-settings-manager
After launching the application, go to 'Window Management' Click on 'Place Windows' and on the General tab, change the option Multi Output Mode to : 'Use output device with pointer'

Hope it helps.

Comment: I know much time has passed but it's worth to say - it's not working.

Comment: @Joe: here's the [bug for this issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/874146) that still hasn't actually been fixed. Look at the tons of duplicated that bug has. I still see the bug in 16.04.1.